# Google Cloud Vision API fails to access Image URLs until 1PM PST

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am working with google cloud vision API safe search function. I am calling the API by passing in the URLs to remote images.

**I noticed that the same image URL fails before 1PM PST, where it works after roughly 1PM.** I have been noticing this pattern for 3 day.

Failing messages (Before 1PM) look something like this:

```
"error": {
        "code": 14,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
```

where as when it works correctly (after 1PM), I can get expected responses like this:

```
        "adult": "UNLIKELY",
        "spoof": "UNLIKELY",
        "medical": "UNLIKELY",
        "violence": "UNLIKELY",
        "racy": "LIKELY"
      }
```

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? I am still on free plan, not sure if that is a problem.

Edit: Adding response -

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 14,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    },
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 4,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    },
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 14,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    },
    {
      "safeSearchAnnotation": {
        "adult": "LIKELY",
        "spoof": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
        "medical": "UNLIKELY",
        "violence": "UNLIKELY",
        "racy": "VERY_LIKELY"
      }
    },
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 4,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    },
    {
      "safeSearchAnnotation": {
        "adult": "UNLIKELY",
        "spoof": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
        "medical": "UNLIKELY",
        "violence": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
        "racy": "VERY_LIKELY"
      }
    },
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 14,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    },
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 14,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    },
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 4,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    },
    {
      "safeSearchAnnotation": {
        "adult": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
        "spoof": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
        "medical": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
        "violence": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
        "racy": "POSSIBLE"
      }
    },
    {
      "safeSearchAnnotation": {
        "adult": "POSSIBLE",
        "spoof": "VERY_LIKELY",
        "medical": "UNLIKELY",
        "violence": "UNLIKELY",
        "racy": "VERY_LIKELY"
      }
    },
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 4,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    },
    {
      "safeSearchAnnotation": {
        "adult": "UNLIKELY",
        "spoof": "LIKELY",
        "medical": "UNLIKELY",
        "violence": "UNLIKELY",
        "racy": "POSSIBLE"
      }
    },
    {
      "safeSearchAnnotation": {
        "adult": "POSSIBLE",
        "spoof": "POSSIBLE",
        "medical": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
        "violence": "UNLIKELY",
        "racy": "VERY_LIKELY"
      }
    },
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 4,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    },
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 14,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    }
  ]
}

200 OK
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using publicly available URLs you will encounter this error from time to time since there is no guarantee that the image is readily available. The host of the image might deny some request for DOS prevention. See [imageUri reference](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageRequest#imagesource) for more details.

> imageUri
>
> The URI of the source image. Can be either:
>
> 1. A Google Cloud Storage URI of the form gs://bucket_name/object_name.
>    Object versioning is not supported. See Google Cloud Storage Request
>    URIs for more info.
> 2. A publicly-accessible image HTTP/HTTPS URL. **When fetching images from
>    HTTP/HTTPS URLs, Google cannot guarantee that the request will be
>    completed. Your request may fail if the specified host denies the
>    request (e.g. due to request throttling or DOS prevention), or if
>    Google throttles requests to the site for abuse prevention.** You should
>    not depend on externally-hosted images for production applications.
>
> When both gcsImageUri and imageUri are specified, imageUri takes
> precedence.

What I could suggest is to download the image locally or put it in cloud storage and from there you can use it as input.

Comment: Hi Ricco,

Thank you for your reply. Why does the API works with URL better in the afternoon than in mornings? 

The URLs are always available as in I can open them in a browser.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure why. But most probably the host of the images might have configured something for maintenance or security on that time that restricts requests from APIs.

Comment: From our end, receiving 200 HTTP code for the whole online batch request (https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate) including some images with same error message “We can not access the URL …”. for different codes of 4 or 14.

(1) We were able to access image URLs at the same time successfully when Google fails.

(2) From google API response, how do we know what errors we met? in above 3 reasons (request throttle, DOS prevention or Google throttles) or other reasons?

(3) What do error codes 4 and 14 mean? Why do they have the same message? Are there any other codes?

Comment: @QiaoranBi You can check the error codes in https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/code.proto hopefully this could help on your investigation. Error 4 means DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, where the deadline expired before the operation could complete. Error 14 could mean a transient error.